# Kubectl tls patch returning “not patched”

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, istio

I am trying to patch **istio-ingressgateway** service with ACM by the following

```
kubectl -n istio-system patch service istio-ingressgateway -p "$(cat<<EOF
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
annotations:
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:xx-xxxx-1:123456789:certificate/xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
EOF
)"
```

but it is returning **not patched**. Whats wrong here?

Comment: `it is showing patched now, but still SSL is not applied to ELB, that's strange` -> there is related [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6566) about that. Specifically take a look at [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6566#issuecomment-427136888) and [this](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6566#issuecomment-428914509) answer. Additionally you can take a look at this [thread](https://discuss.istio.io/t/503-errors-when-using-tls-on-gateway/6127/6) at discuss.istio.io. Let me know if that solved your problem.

Comment: @Jakub Thanks it helps..

Comment: Happy to help. I have posted an answer with that informations for future visilibty. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted or up vote it so people know that's the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the indentation try to put your patch on a yaml file:

**ingress_patch.yaml**

```yaml
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: "arn:aws:acm:xx-xxxx-1:123456789:certificate/xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: "tcp"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "443"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-proxy-protocol: "*"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  selector:
    app: istio-ingressgateway
    istio: ingressgateway
```

Then apply it as follows:

```
kubectl -n istio-system patch service istio-ingressgateway -p "$(cat ./ingress_patch.yaml)"
```

Comment: Thanks, it is showing patched now, but still SSL is not applied to ELB, that's strange

Answer (score 3):

I am posting this as a community wiki answer for better visibility.

---

As I mentioned in comments there is related github issue about [Istio Ingress TLS key management use ACM](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6566).

Despite what @wolmi said what is true, because the indentation was wrong, there are more issues which need to be covered when you're trying to combine [istio](https://istio.io/) with [ELB](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) and ACM.

It's well described in 3 below answers.

---

Especially worth to take look and 3 below comments from above github issue.

- [Answer](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6566#issuecomment-427136888) provided by @cmcconnell1.
- [Answer](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6566#issuecomment-428914509) provided by @eduardobaitello
- [Answer](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/6566#issuecomment-428603221) provided by @eduardobaitello

---

Additionally [there](https://discuss.istio.io/t/503-errors-when-using-tls-on-gateway/6127/6) is a thread about that on discuss.istio.io